# Get subscribers with a changed status during last X days

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, unsubscribe

We would like to send a list of subscribers' status changes both from "Active" to "Unsubscribed" and vice versa to SFTP. We would like to run this activity two or three times an hour to imitate real-time behavior. (The alternative was to create a dedicated landing page, but the client currently does not have the budget for that.)

The solution in my head is to save a snapshot of the All Subscriber's list in a separate DE every one or two days and get the changed statuses by comparing that old snapshot to the current data.

But I am wondering if there is a more straightforward way of handling this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is pretty straightforward and simple to execute.

You could think that the [_Subscribers](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_subscribers.htm&type=5) data view could be used for this, but it would only allow you to identify people that:

- are subscribed currently
- are unsubscribed currently

You will not be able to identify people who were unsubscribed and and decided to resubscribe as those records will not be distinguishable from people who never unsubscribed:

- the `Status` for both is active,
- `DateJoined` never changes (regardless of unsubscribing and resubscribing)
- the `DateUnsubuscribed` disappears when the Status becomes active

In short:
go with the copy data extension.

Answer (score 2):

You can also extract and import the [**Status Change**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_statuschanges.htm&type=5) tracking data, which would be much less data than maintaining two data extensions of every subscriber.

The most recent record for a subscriber is the current status.

Comment: This could be an even better solution. Let me try it out!

Comment: I tested your solution out Adam and it works very well. However, I need to (1) fetch this info more than once a day e.g. 4 times per hour and the Tracking Extracts option did not allow me that. Also, there are fields from other DEs that I need to fetch for the output file. I, of course, did not mention this in the question. But I think I would go with the two DE solution for now. But thanks as always for the suggestion and I may use that in other instances.

Comment: There will definitely be a lag with this solution, but I can envision a tracking extract/import and query automation that maintains a DE of changes in the past day.  I've worked with a couple of clients that the changes in status were important and they opted for refreshing it daily.

Comment: Four times/hour isn't an option in an Automation schedule either, btw.  Unless you use 4 identical Automations on staggered schedules.

Comment: You are right. But there is the hourly repeat option on the schedule dropdown.